# `generic :: write(formatted)` subroutines in gfortran being called by other derived types

Tags: generics, fortran, gfortran

I am using several derived types. For debugging purposes, I would like to nicely print them on screen by using a `generic :: write(formatted)`.

Here is an example program showing what I mean:

```
program main
  use :: test_mod
  implicit none

  type(test1) :: t1
  type(test2) :: t2

  t1 = test1(name="t1")
  t2 = test2(name="t2", t1)
  print *, 'Test1:', t1
  print *, 'Test2:', t2
end program
```

Here is the module:

```
module test_mod
  implicit none
  private
  public :: test1, test2

  type :: test1
    character(2) :: name
  contains
    procedure, private :: test1_writef
    generic :: write(formatted) => test1_writef
  end type test1

  type :: test2
    character(2) :: name
    type(test1) :: t1
  contains
    procedure, private :: test2_writef
    generic :: write(formatted) => test2_writef
  end type test2

contains

  subroutine test1_writef(self, unit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
    class(test1), intent(in)    :: self      ! Object to write.
    integer, intent(in)         :: unit      ! Internal unit to write to.
    character(*), intent(in)    :: iotype    ! LISTDIRECTED or DTxxx
    integer, intent(in)         :: v_list(:) ! parameters from fmt spec.
    integer, intent(out)        :: iostat    ! non zero on error, etc.
    character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg     ! define if iostat non zero.
    write (unit, "(a)", IOSTAT=iostat, IOMSG=iomsg) self%name
  end subroutine test1_writef

  subroutine test2_writef(self, unit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
    class(test2), intent(in)    :: self      ! Object to write.
    integer, intent(in)         :: unit      ! Internal unit to write to.
    character(*), intent(in)    :: iotype    ! LISTDIRECTED or DTxxx
    integer, intent(in)         :: v_list(:) ! parameters from fmt spec.
    integer, intent(out)        :: iostat    ! non zero on error, etc.
    character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg     ! define if iostat non zero.
    write (unit, "(a, ' <', a, '>')", IOSTAT=iostat, IOMSG=iomsg) self%name, self%t1
  end subroutine test2_writef

end module test_mod
```

Running this program I expected to obtain:

```
Test1: t1
Test2: t2 <t1>
```

But instead with gfortran I obtain:

```
Test1: t1
Test2: t2 <>
```

The "t1" string **is not written on screen**.

I am using this version of gfortran:

```
[egissi@shibax ~]$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I know that I could just replace `self%t1` with `self%t1%name`, but my types are much more complicated than that and I would better not repeat the same format in other derived types.

**What am I missing? How can I obtain that behaviour?**

Comment: `"(a, ' <', dt, '>')"` instead?

Comment: This is what Francescalus is suggesting: (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS2MB5_14.1.0/com.ibm.xlf141.bg.doc/language_ref/dtediting.html) She/he saved my day. How can I promote your comment to answer? What bibliography can you suggest me to improve my OO Fortran skills?

Comment: You can do that only by answering yourself. Remeber a good answer should also explain the code, not just list it. Perhaps francescalus will answer? If not, answer yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a defined output procedure to be used it must be "selected" in some way.  In the list-directed output

```
print *, 'Test1:', t1
print *, 'Test2:', t2
```

the procedures `test1_writef` and `test2_writef` are available for the effective items `t1` and `t2`.  They are therefore used.

However, for the child output

```
write (unit, "(a, ' <', a, '>')", IOSTAT=iostat, IOMSG=iomsg) self%name, self%t1
```

we now have an explicit format (`"(a,' <',a,'>')"`).  Here the effective items `self%name` and `self%t1` are edited explicitly as characters.  To request the object `self%t1` be processed according to `test1_writef` it is necessary to explicitly use a `dt` edit descriptor:

```
write (unit, "(a, ' <', dt, '>')", IOSTAT=iostat, IOMSG=iomsg) self%name, self%t1
```

Comment: This isn't to say that `Test2: t2 <>` is the correct output from the original code.